# How do I change human_time_diff function language in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress website and I would like to have the "posted X hours ago" in my post list. I found out that this can be easily done by calling the human_time_diff function.

The problem is that it returns the string in English (for instance 2 HOURS).
My website is in Portuguese, so I would like to have it in Portuguese.

How do I change the language this function returns?

Thanks,
Oscar

Edit: I found [this link](http://limbotech.net/alterando-o-sistema-de-data-do-wordpress-para-o-tempo-humano/) but this solution is simple rewriting the function

Comment: Is your wordpress installation in english or portuguese? Usually using a portuguese installation forces wordpress to use a portuguese language file, which then prints the time difference in correct portuguese. The function `_n(...)` from the original code is used for translation. You can also change the language of your installation afterwards.

Comment: I will try that. If I hire a hosting service with a pre-installed WP I am also able to change its language, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. Changing the language afterwards requires that you're able to make changes to the `wp-config.php`-file. Further steps are described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language#Manually_Installing_Language_Files)

Comment: Ok, thanks! Could you please post it as an answer do I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your wordpress installation in english or portuguese?

Usually using a portuguese installation forces wordpress to use a portuguese language file, which then prints the time difference in correct portuguese. The function `_n(...)` from the original code is used for translation.

You can also change the language of your installation afterwards.

Changing the language afterwards requires that you're able to make changes to the `wp-config.php`-file. Further steps are described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language#Manually_Installing_Language_Files)